# Mutli Input/Output mixer setup

Tags: mixer, mixers, windows-10

I recently bought a mixer (Yamaha MG10XU) to go with my headphone/mic combo. I'm basically wondering how would one go to have a following setup.

Right now Windows is using multi track thanks to [Voicemeeter Potato](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/potato.htm) (So that I can manually change the volume of let's say, browser, music, audio communication).

[image: Voicemeeter Potato setup]

To that I have a analog mixer in USB to take the microphone sound into the pc.

However what I would like to do is to take care of all that on a mixer only.

But the main wall I keep hitting is that basically I think I would need a mixer with at least two output track (since I don't want the mic sound to be mixed with everything else when talking).

So ideally it would be :

- One track with only the mic sent to the pc (and potentially also routed to other output track
- One track that would take whatever input I give (basically mimicking what Voicemeeter currently does) and send it to my headphones or speakers (to my choosing).

Only thing I found so far would be something like the `Soundcraft Signature 22 MTK`, but I don't know if there is a better solution out there

If anyone could give me pointers on how one could achieve this I would be really grateful (or if it's not realistic too)

Comment: Digital mixer, USB interface with multitrack input.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Mark Ididn't look too much around digital mixer because they seem pricier, but is there no way to handle that with an analog one ?

Comment: you're unlikely to find an analogue mixer with multichannel digital interface unfortunately.